# Java - JMockit testing 2 injected classes with the same field names

Tags: java, jmockit

I created a test class for abstract ClassA. But i encountered an error **Missing @Injectable for field "ClassC" in ClassB**.

I tried renaming one of the ClassC field names and it worked. ***But*** ***how can I fix this error without renaming field name of ClassC?***

My codes below :

```
abstract ClassA extends ClassB {

    @Inject
    ClassC classC;
}

abstract ClassB {

    @Inject
    ClassC classC; 
}

//---------------- Test class for ClassA* 

@RunWith(JMockit.class) 

ClassATest {

   @Injectable
   ClassC classC;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Tested`](https://jmockit.github.io/gettingStarted.html#testedObjects) annotion and set `fullyInitialized = true`.

```
public final class ExampleIntegrationTest {
    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true) 
    private ClassA classA;

    @Mocked
    private ClassC classC;

    //testMethod
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked. I have additional question. I need to initialize ClassC. Is there a way not to use @Mocked? Instead, i will use @Injectable?

Comment: @KarlDaven I think it is ok. Injectable is more powerful, and can do everything mocked does.

Comment: I tried using Injectable but my issue is ClassC of ClassB is null. Only ClassC of ClassA was set. Is this correct? <pre>ClassA extends ClassB
{
 Inject
 ClassC c;

 method(){
 super.method();
 }
}

ClassB {
 Inject
 ClassC c;

 method(){
 c.set(obj);
 }
}

ClassC {
 // has getter setter of obj
}

RunWith(JMockit.class)
ClassATest {

 Tested (fullyInitialized = true)
 ClassA a;

 Injectable
 Class c;

 @Before
 public void setup(){
  this.a = new ClassD();
 }

 Test
 public void testMethod(){
  this.a.method();
  **ClassC of ClassB is null.
 }

}</pre>

Comment: Try remove setup method. With @Tested, jmockit will initiate tested class and inject dependency automatically.

Comment: @KarlDaven see above reply

Comment: I see. thank you for your suggestion! I also have question. Does fullyInitialized also applied when using Arquillian?